# SwiftUI TabView image size does not match LaunchScreen.storyboard UITabBar, unable to fix

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode-storyboard

I'm configuring my launchscreen storyboard to show a `UITabBar` that corresponds to rest of my app, built using SwiftUI. I haven't worked with auto layout or storyboards much.

This is the code I'm using to structure my `TabView` for the rest of my app, once loaded:

```
TabView {
    View1()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "pin.fill")
            Text("Monkeys")
        }
    ...
```

I haven't configured the `UITabBar` in the StoryBoard other than the image and title values.

When the app is launching (using LaunchScreen.storyboard `UITabBar`) the bar looks like this:

[image: Tab view with larger images]

When the app has loaded (using SwiftUI `TabView`)

[image: Tab view with smaller images]

How can I adjust the size of the images in StoryBoard to fit the rest of my app?

I've tried messing with the size inspector, but it doesn't affect the image size. I also can't seem to change the `Image` size of the `TabView` in SwiftUI using `.frame()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I'm using is to manually set the font size of the SF Symbols using:

```
Image(systemName: "flag.fill")
    .font(.system(size: 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the TabView contentMode is set to the same value in both the storyboard and SwiftUI for example contentMode = .scaleToFill